# How can I add this function in my Meteor project

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I installed type.js package and when I type this code directly in the console it works:

```
$(function(){
                  $(".typedelement").typed({
                    strings: ["You don't have any projects yet", "Start by adding a project."],
                    typeSpeed: 0
                  });
              });
});
```

however how can I add it on my js file so it works for the end client to see it?

I try registering it as a template helper and then calling the helper insdide the template but it returns an object, any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins should be initialized in your template's [onRendered](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) callback. For example:

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  $(".typedelement").typed({
    strings: ["You don't have any projects yet", "Start by adding a project."],
    typeSpeed: 0
  });
});
```

Comment: It worked perfectly and will learn more about it from Meteor docs, thanks!